# Querying data between three tables in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a serious problem as i am new in yii2 and new in coding.

**My problem is**: I need to get data in  Gridview of model PurchaseOrder from model EmpInfo. EmpInfo model have primary key emp_code which is foreign key to PurchaseOrder model as requested_by.

Now by yii2 join i have emp_code in requested_by field but i need to show emp_name in requested_by field of purchase_order and emp_name is EmpInfo model which has primary key emp_code . How can i do it in yii2 ?

So far I had tried like this:

```
    $abc=\app\models\PurchaseOrder::findOne(['purchase_order'=>$model->id])->requested_by;
    // $v=  $abc=\app\models\EmpInfo::find()->select('emp_name')->where(['emp_code' =>$abc->requested_by]);
    print_r($abc);
    exit();
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Paste your GridView code here

Comment: Please share your gridview code and database attributes if possibel so that some get clear idea and help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple:

```
$abc = \app\models\PurchaseOrder::findOne(['purchase_order'=>$model->id]);
$empname = $abc->requested_by0->emp_name;
```